# Is it safe to use functions from numpy.core.*?

Tags: python, numpy

To motivate the question: In recent NumPy versions there is a performance issue with `numpy.clip` and in the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14281) a suggested workaround is to use `numpy.core.umath.clip`.

I couldn't really find anything about the purpose of the `numpy.core.umath` or more generally the `numpy.core.*` modules.  `pydoc` shows documentation for them but they seem not to be included in the [online documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/).  Therefore I am a bit unsure if it is safe (in the sense of having a stable API) to use functions from these modules or if they should rather be seen as internals that may change between releases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `numpy.core` states:

> Please note that this module is **private**.  All functions and objects are available in the main `numpy` namespace - **use that instead**.

This submodule is apparently not meant to be used by end-users. This is also why there is almost no online documentation about it. The functions in this submodule are more likely to change in the future than the regular ones in provided in `numpy`.

Comment: It seems this note was added in recent versions, it is not yet there in 1.17.4 (hence I didn't find it).  But I assume it applies to all versions.